# Stop Retreating

Tags: crusader-kings-2

Sometimes in decisive battles I accidentally misclick another area to retreat, which generally ends up just killing my army. Is there a way to stop retreating once you start? I was about to start ironman and don't wish to lose 100 hours of playtime because one misclick gets all my units killed in the middle of a decisive war.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is unfortunately, no, you have to retreat once you've started to retreat. It's annoying, but generally you do poorly in ironman for other reasons. A battle doesn't decide the war, so to speak. Unless it does. Then you're just out of luck. ;)